# Error when trying to use useRef on a page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to use useRef() and componentDidMount() to autofocus an input field on a page. Here's the page code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from '../..//styles/Home.module.css'


interface Props {
}

class Test extends Component<Props>  {
  nameRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  componentDidMount() {
    this.nameRef.current!.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <form action="/account/sign-up" method="post">
          <label htmlFor="last">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required ref={this.nameRef} />
          <label htmlFor="first">Email address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </main>
    )
  }

}

export default Test
```

However I get an error at runtime: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` This error is at the `nameRef = React.useRef..` line.

Comment: You can't use hooks in a class-based component. You'll need to either use the class-based-style refs or move the whole component to be functional (I'd recommend this).

Comment: Use [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must not write hooks in class-based component. In order to use hooks you must rewrite your component to a functional component.

**UPDATED**

I misunderstood question and thats why my answer is probably not complete. If you wan to use refs with class based component you should use React.createRef() function.

Comment: Using React.createRef() fixed the problem! Thanks! The new line is: ``nameRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();``